# How can I change Twitter Bootstrap 3 Vertical variation Hover Color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 Vertical variation Dropdown menu for my sidebar. I want to style the Dropdown Hover Color but I didn't find any CSS element there I could edit it. Can anyone please help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown hover color can be changed using this CSS selector:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
color: #ddd;}`

Answer (score 0):

In the future, your best option would be to use your developer tools to tell you exactly what needs to be changed. In Google Chrome, you would right click on whatever element you would like to change, at the bottom of the popup list is 'Inspect Element'.

At the bottom of the screen, you should see a horizontal menu with 'Elements', 'Network', 'Sources', etc. If it is not already selected, click the 'Elements' tab. Now you can hover your mouse over the various HTML elements until the one you want is highlighted, and on the right side of that menu, you should see another one with 'Styles' as the first icon. In that you can freely change things to see if it had the desired effect and once you do get the right element to do what you want, you can simply copy the value from chrome and paste it into your css file for a permanent change that will persist.

I apologize if you already knew all of that. I just remember when I first got going, little tricks like the one I shared above would have saved me HOURS of fiddling.

Check out this video for more cool things Chrome can do: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaneWEqNcpE

Last thing, if you aren't already using them, try Chrome or Firefox for development.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh, just now realizing this thread is three years old... Oh well!